# How to sed -i '`[echo $var]`i word' file?

Tags: shell, sed, variable

Code:

```
pos=2;
printf "Masi \nwas \nhere" > /tmp/1
sed -i '`echo $pos`i huhu' /tmp/1
```

Expected output:

```
Masi 
huhu 
was 
here
```

Current output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: ``'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions in the apostrophes are not evaluated (nor subshell nor variables). You need to use normal quotes:

```
$ pos=2;
$ printf "Masi \nwas \nhere" > /tmp/1
$ sed -i "`echo $pos`i huhu" /tmp/1
$ cat /tmp/1
Masi 
huhu
was 
here
```

which is equivalent of

```
$ sed -i "${pos}i huhu" /tmp/1
```

(without the subshell)

Comment: Why keep the `echo`? It's another layer of indirection that doesn't seem to be required

Comment: @roaima Yes, that is a useless. I wanted to point out only the problem that was causing the error. I will add also this note. Thanks for mentioning it.